# SICP, Scheme, DrRacket Question: Timer/profiler function?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, sicp

I'm currently trying to do exercise 1.22, which needs a function called runtime that returns the number of milliseconds the system has been running. However, my environment (R5RS) does not seem to have this. It does not have time, current-milliseconds, current-inexact-milliseconds, etc, either.

What function do I have access to, to profile my function? Which functions returns the number of milliseconds, microseconds, etc, that have passed? I would of course prefer the highest precision timer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the best thing to do is switch the language in DrRacket to "Use the language declared in the source", and start your file with `#lang racket`.  Then functions like `current-seconds` and friends will be available.

Alternatively, you could use the profiling library, available via `(require profile)` and documented [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/profile/index.html).

Finally, you might want to look at Neil Van Dyke's [SICP library for DrRacket](http://www.neilvandyke.org/sicp-plt/).

Answer (score 1):

I used [current-inexact-milliseconds](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._current-inexact-milliseconds%29%29) when I did that exercise.  **Spoiler Alert:** You can see my solution on my blog at [SICP Exercise 1.22: Timed Prime Test](http://www.billthelizard.blogspot.com/2010/02/sicp-exercise-122-timed-prime-test.html).

By the way, I only solved that problem after asking a similar question, [Is there an equivalent to Lisp's “runtime” primitive in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195105/is-there-an-equivalent-to-lisps-runtime-primitive-in-scheme)

Comment: As I stated in my post, current-inexact-milliseconds does NOT work. I get the following error: reference to undefined identifier: current-inexact-milliseconds. What environment are you using?

Comment: @KnowsLittle: I run DrScheme with the Language "Module" selected to do the SICP exercises.  Sorry, I thought I had mentioned that in the linked article.  I'll need to update that.